# How can I move image with the KeyBoard using 2 keys?

Tags: c#, forms, class, events

I have a problem that I'm struggling with..
I want to move an image using my keyboard to the left, right, up or down and in a diagonal way.
I searched the web and found, that to use 2 diffrent keys I need to remember the previous key, so for that I'm using a bool dictionary.

in my main Form class this is how the KeyDown event looks like:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    baseCar.carAccelerate(e.KeyCode.ToString().ToLower());
    carBox.Refresh(); //carbox is a picturebox in my form that store the image I want to move.
}
```

My KeyUp event:

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    baseCar.carBreak(e.KeyCode.ToString().ToLower());
}
```

My Paint event:

```
private void carBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Car, baseCar.CharPosX, baseCar.CharPosY); // Car is just an image
}
```

And my baseCar class:

private Dictionary KeysD = new Dictionary();
// there is a method to set the W|A|S|D Keys, like: KeysD.Add("w",false)

```
    public void carAccelerate(string moveDir)
    {       
        KeysD[moveDir] = true;
        moveBeta();
    }
    public void moveBeta()
    {
        if (KeysD["w"])
        {
            this.CharPosY -= this.carMoveYSpeed;
        }
        if (KeysD["s"])
        {
            CharPosY += carMoveYSpeed;
        }
        if (KeysD["a"])
        {
            CharPosX -= carMoveXSpeed;
        }
        if (KeysD["d"])
        {
            CharPosX += carMoveXSpeed;
        }
    }
    public void carBreak(string str)
    {
        KeysD[str] = false;
    }
```

Anyway it works, but my problem is that I can't get back to the first pressed key for example:

I pressed W to move up and then the D key to go diagonal, how ever when I release the D key it wont go Up again because the KeyDown event is "dead" and wont call the carAccelerate() method again..
and I can't figure out how to fix it..

Can any one help me please?
Maybe there is a better way to handle the keys? im open to any ideas!
And I hope you can understand it, my english isnt the best :S

Answer (score 1):

Store all keystates and don't animate on keypress, but for example using a timer.

Then:

```
KeyDown(key)
{
   KeyState[key] = true;
}

KeyUp(key)
{
   KeyState[key] = false;
}

Timer_Tick()
{
    Animate();
}    

Animate()
{
    if (KeyState["W"])
    {
        // Accelerate
    }
    if (KeyState["S"])
    {
        // Decelerate
    }

}
```

Then in the `KeyDown` method you can check for conflicting keys (what if accelerate + decelerate are pressed at the same time, and so on).